# How to hide a part of the url using htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rewrite rules in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ system.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

With this rules I am getting the url as follows.

http://www.example.com/1111/article-title

I want to hide the "1111" from the url while passing that to the system.php as an argument.Also I need to add some text instead of "1111". So my url should be as follows.

http://www.example.com/text-article-title

Is there any way to do this? Please give some insight on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^example.com/1111/article-title [NC]
RewriteRule ^example.com/(.*)$ example.com/text-article-title/$1 [L]
```

that should do the trick.